# Couldn't match expected type '([Char], b0)' with actual type '[[Char]]'

Tags: haskell, types

first time working with haskell and I keep running into this issue:

```
Couldn't match expected type `([Char], b0)'
        with actual type `[[Char]]'
In the first argument of `fst', namely `moves'
In the second argument of `rotatedMaze', namely `(fst moves)'
```

I can't quite figure out what is going on. Where is my parameter error?

```
manyPlayersManyRotations :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
manyPlayersManyRotations maze moves = 
    if null moves
        then maze
        else  
            let     
                rmaze = rotatedMaze maze (fst moves)
                drop1 = dropPlayer rmaze '1'
                opor1 = (fst drop1, snd drop1)
                drop2 = dropPlayer (fst opor1) '2'
                opor2 = (fst drop2, snd opor2 || snd drop2)
                drop3 = dropPlayer (fst opor2) '3'
                opor3 = (fst drop3, snd opor2 || snd drop3)
                drop4 = dropPlayer (fst opor3) '4'
                opor4 = (fst drop4, snd opor2 || snd drop4)
            in 
                if (not)(snd opor4)
                    then fst opor4
                    else manyPlayersManyRotations (fst opor4) (tail moves)

rotatedMaze :: [[Char]] -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
rotatedMaze maze move = 
    if move == ['c']
        then rc maze
        else if move == ['c','c']
                then rcc maze
                    else r180 maze
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fst` wants a tuple, but you gave it a list.

The type of `fst` is:

```
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

The first line of the error message

```
Couldn't match expected type `([Char], b0)'
```

says the expected type for the argument in your call to `fst` is `([Char], b0)`. The `[Char]` bit is inferred from context, and `b0` just means it doesn't care what that second type is (because `fst` just discards the second tuple element).

The second line of the error message

```
with actual type `[[Char]]'
```

says you passed it a `[[Char]]` instead, because... well, that's what you've done.

Perhaps what you meant instead of `fst` is `head`, which gives the first element of a list.

Answer (score 2):

`fst` and `snd` are defined for 2-tuples, here your argument is a list `[[Char]]`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I forgot that I needed to use head there. You are a life saver!